# Oracle Database with SSRS reports

Tags: visual-studio, oracle, reporting-services

Using SSRS with Oracle DB is not orthodox, but still i am forced to use it.
So, while i am working on my reports, if another collegue of mine tries to do a query on the same database, an error occurs, on the TNS Listener. When i check the number of sessions active or inactive, they are in the limit secified. After i close and reopen the SSRS project from Visual Studio it works and also it reduces the number of sessions.

Is there a way to make oracle accept more sessions? or any other solution?

PS: Oracle version 10g, Visual Studio version 2005

Comment: What's the error reported on the TNS listener?

Answer (score 0):

I am using SSRS 2005 to report off Oracle 10g, and I haven't seen this issue. How is your colleague querying the database, and what drivers are you using?

Comment: I think it says that TNS could not be found, or something similar, the problem is that it's not from tnsnames.ora config file, that is okay, the problem is from the many simultaneous connections that SSRS opens when editing a report. I tried increasing the maximum sessions number and the maximum processes number, maybe that would give me a resolution. i only have about 50 sessions so it might be from this, or it just might be from the oracle server configuration. we both have oracle 10g client on our machines...